My token cannot be displayed in Phantom. why？
I can’t find this token on Phantom, but it can be found on-chain and in DEX. It’s very strange. Why is this happening? Can it be fixed?
2FabGE6ukmSFfgNtFc7Y7icCyXqdhuBPazv6Z2mHpump

Because of it’s name, applications like Phantom and Birdeye filter for words that maybe offensive.

It doesn’t seem to be because of the name. I searched for words like “f*ck,” and they can all be searched on Phantom.
